# Accessing the Ethereum State Variables using web3js (Java Script)

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, javascript, events, state-variable

I'm trying to run the below code to get the state variables using the getIdBytes method of the Smart Contract, and assign it to a java script array variable, but it doesn't seem to work.

All I can do is print the returned values using console.log(return).

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

```
var coreValues = ['Apple', 'Banana'];
console.log("Before call :"  + coreValues[1]);

if (get_flag)
{
contract3.methods.getIdBytes(index1, abstract_contract_address).call().then(function(result){
   for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  coreValues[i] =  result[i];
  console.log("Inside Function Call" + coreValues[i]);
  }
});

console.log("After Call :" + coreValues[0]);
```

Here's what the output looks like.

```
Before call :Banana
After Call :Apple
Inside Function call : Steve
Inside Function call : Rogers
Inside Function call : Male
Inside Function call : 0987654
Inside Function call : 12/05/1980
```

Should I be using *events*?

Answer (score 0):

Execution of the web3js call is asynchronous, so "After Call" is executed before the code inside the loop.

Try this:

```
var coreValues = ['Apple', 'Banana'];
console.log("Before call :"  + coreValues[1]);

if (get_flag) {
  contract3.methods.getIdBytes(index1, abstract_contract_address).call().then(function(result){
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      coreValues[i] =  result[i];
      console.log("Inside Function Call" + coreValues[i]);
    }
    console.log("End of Call :" + coreValues[0]);
    // continue with your logic here...
  });
}
console.log("Too early: " + coreValues[0]);
```

Another option is to use "await":

```
var coreValues = ['Apple', 'Banana'];
console.log("Before call :"  + coreValues[1]);

if (get_flag) {
  await contract3.methods.getIdBytes(index1, abstract_contract_address).call().then(function(result){
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      coreValues[i] =  result[i];
      console.log("Inside Function Call" + coreValues[i]);
    }
  });
}
console.log("Not too early: " + coreValues[0]);
// continue with your logic here...
```